# Android: widget stops receiving any intents after killed using task manager/

Tags: android, android-widget, android-intent

I've got an application with a widget in one .apk file.

Widget reacts on incoming sms and other app-specific events. And also it launches the main activity when user clicks on it.

The problem is that when user starts an activity (clicking on a widget or from applications menu - doesn't matter) and then kills an application using task manager - my widget stops receiving any intents (like TIME_TICK).

I know that solution for my problem exists (I saw apps in android market which widgets are able to launch an activity after it was killed by user)

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:a="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="ru.studiomobile">
    <application a:icon="@drawable/icon" a:label="@string/app_name">
        <!-- Widget -->
        <receiver a:name=".widget.WidgetProvider" a:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action a:name="android.MyWidget.ACTION_ON_WIDGET_CLICK"/>
                <action a:name="android.MyWidget.ACTION_CHANGE_DAY_NIGHT"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data a:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                       a:resource="@xml/widget_provider"/>
        </receiver>

        <service a:name=".widget.UpdateService" a:label="UpdateService"
                a:exported="false">

            <intent-filter>
                <action a:name="android.MyWidget.ACTION_ON_WIDGET_CLICK"/>
                <action a:name="android.MyWidget.ACTION_CHANGE_DAY_NIGHT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you show your manifest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you need to have a service http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html
 instead of just activity. Service monitors incoming sms.